# SQL - delete rows in all tables based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a MySQL database with some hundreds tables.

I need to delete records in all tables based on a common column named 'companyId' - this column is present in all tables of the database.

How I can delete all records in all tables where columnId = somenumber ?

Thank you in advance !

Ivano C.

@SocratesG I tried your stored procedure but I get the below creating the SP:

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@TableName VARCHAR(128);

```
DECLARE @MyColumn VARCHAR(128);
SET @MyColumn = 'compan' at line 4

SQL Statement:
CREATE PROCEDURE `deletePortalInstance` ()

BEGIN

    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @MyColumn VARCHAR(128);

    SET @MyColumn = 'companyId'

    DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
        (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.id) AS ObjectName 
        FROM dbo.syscolumns c 
        WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id,'ISTABLE') = 1 --Search for tables only
        AND c.name = @MyColumn)

    OPEN MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor into @TableName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

    BEGIN

        EXEC('DELETE '+@MyColumn+' FROM '+@TableName+' WHERE '+@MyColumn+' = 906454')
        FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor into @TableName

    END

    CLOSE MyCursor   
    DEALLOCATE MyCursor

END
```

Comment: Set up your tables with proper foreign keys!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(128);
DECLARE @MyColumn VARCHAR(128);
SET @MyColumn = 'MyColumnName'
DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR  
(SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.id) as ObjectName
              FROM dbo.syscolumns c
              WHERE 
                OBJECTPROPERTY(c.id,'ISTABLE') = 1 --Search for tables only
                AND c.name = @MyColumn)

OPEN MyCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor into @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
    EXEC
            (
                 'DELETE ' + @MyColumn
                +' FROM ' + @TableName  
                +' WHERE ' + @MyColumn + ' <= 1000'
            )
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor into @TableName
END
CLOSE MyCursor   
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

Comment: I'll try, but what is mean ' <= 1000' ?

Comment: you can use your own value there

Comment: You mean the value matching the records that I'll to delete ?

Comment: Yes, write there the value that matches the records you want to delete.

Comment: I'll try in a few times ! Excuse me for the delay

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM companyId where columnId = 1
```

Comment: I have a MySQL database with some HUNDREDS tables so I I need to delete records in all tables based on a common column named 'companyId' with a BATCH process, not table by table

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM <tblName> where columnId = <Your Column Id val>
```

But i think you use referential integrity constraint using foreign keys and use **On Delete Cascade**

As per your new info,

**Update :**

```
DELETE t1, t2
      FROM <table1> t1
      JOIN <table2> t2 ON t1.columnId = t2.columnId 
     WHERE t1.columnId  = <Your Column Value>
```

Explanation :

1. Here we are deleting records from multiple tables ,so we use `DELETE FROM table1,table2` etc
2. As you have one column with same name in all tables , we made `JOIN` so all rows in 100 tables can be deleted at once.

3.At last we have condition like  `WHERE t1.columnId  = 1` , means in table1 , check for columnId = 1 , so as we joined , it selects ALL such rows in 100 table and then DELETES it.

Comment: I have a MySQL database with some HUNDREDS tables so I I need to delete records in all tables based on a common column named 'companyId' with a BATCH process, not table by table

Comment: `common column named 'companyId' ` ? Is this column name same in 100 tables  ?

Comment: Yes, I have some HUNDREDS tables and in all tables there is a column named 'companyId'

Comment: I don't understand - basic DELETE syntax is DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value;  I have hundreads of tables so what are t1 and t2 ?

Comment: First try query , I tried and it worked , I explain answer , wait 4 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM table_Name where columnn_name = value ;
```

example

```
DELETE fom students where rll_num = 5 ;
```

Comment: I have a MySQL database with some HUNDREDS tables so I I need to delete records in all tables based on a common column named 'companyId' with a BATCH process, not table by table